Memory Saturation and Kernel Restart when Converting to np.array in Python
I'm encountering a memory issue when converting my processed data to a numpy array. I have 57GB of RAM, but the RAM saturates quickly and the kernel restarts at np.array(processed_X). Here is my code:
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
from skimage.transform import resize
from tqdm import tqdm

def apply_stft(signal, nperseg=256, noverlap=128):
    f, t, Zxx = scipy.signal.stft(signal, nperseg=nperseg, noverlap=noverlap)
    return np.abs(Zxx)

def resize_stft(stft_result, output_shape=(224, 224)):
    return resize(stft_result, output_shape, mode='constant')

def process_dataset(X):
    processed_X = []
    for example in tqdm(X):
        stft_results = [apply_stft(example[:, i]) for i in range(example.shape[1])]
        resized_stft = [resize_stft(stft) for stft in stft_results]
        stacked_stft = np.stack(resized_stft, axis=-1)
        processed_X.append(stacked_stft)
        del stft_results, resized_stft, stacked_stft
    print(len(processed_X))
    print('FINISHED !!!')
    return np.array(processed_X)

When the code reaches np.array(processed_X), my RAM usage spikes rapidly, eventually consuming all available memory and causing the kernel to restart. How can I avoid this memory issue?
Thank you for your help!
Steps Taken:

Tried deleting intermediate variables to free up memory.
Verified that the issue occurs at the np.array(processed_X) line.


Welcome to StackOverflow. The provided code is not very useful since we have no information about the size of processed_X nor its content. This is certainly why Numpy allocate a big array : the list is certainly too big. The kernel is certainly killed by the OOM killer so to avoid your whole system to be irresponsive due to the lack of available RAM. Please provide a (minimal) reproducible example or (precise) debugging information. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Thank you for your answer, the X has this shape (12225 , 400 , 6 )
For example :
X = np.random.rand(12225, 400, 6)
processed_X = process_dataset(X)
This will give you the same problem. I don't know if it's clear now ?

There are 12225 iterations and each append an FP64-based array of shape (224, 224, 6) taking 1.15 MiB. Thus the final list takes about 14 GiB. Numpy need at least the same space for the final array. Moreover, it may allocate a twice bigger array regarding the implementaiton which may not be aware of the final array size. This means 28-42 GiB of RAM which is a lot!

The good point is that you can know the size of the output so you can allocate directly the output array and fill it in the loop rather than creating a list of many arrays. This should divide the amount of required memory by 2 or 3. Something like 14 GiB. And solve your memory problem.
